# Is there a way to access images outside the root directory in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

The idea is to upload images in a folder outside React root folder with Express, and then by using the image name from the database, get the image file from the folder.

[image]

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
})
```

Comment: Please edit your question to paste your code directly in the question and not as an image.

Comment: I am not sure if you meant to ask that you could upload the images to the server ? and then serve them from the server in terms of a url. This link provides the answer. https://codeburst.io/react-image-upload-with-kittens-cc96430eaece